# Which virtualenv tool is used by PyChart to create virtual envs

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

PyChart has a configuration window to configure virtual env:

[image]

Does anybody know what tool does it use to create those virtualenvs, e.g. venv or virtualenv or pipenv? Or maybe it's something propriatary for PyChart?

Comment: nothing is propriatary for them as virtualenv / pyenv/venv/ are open source. not conda. 
you can create virtual env with any tool and can add the path for them in interpreter setting which pycharm will take. only difference is support as pycharm profession support wsl which community edition doesn't support

Comment: PyChart or PyCharm? If it's PyChart can you please fix the tag?

Comment: @sahasrara62, _and can add the path for them in interpreter setting which pycharm will take_ - how to do that? Which one does it take by default - venv?

Comment: @phd, yeah, it's PyCharm, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @MaxKoretskyi in bottom corner where python version is shown, click on there, add interpreter option come there, give the path there or in settings>project>python-interpreter, add interpreter path there. it will take configured one.  for wsl or docker support community edition won't work, paid one will work

Comment: @sahasrara62, but by default you don't know which one PyCharm uses?

Comment: by default it usually pick the system level interpreter (normal python one which is installed in system at default location) after that it check for pyenv / conda local installation . but normal python is default one /usr/bin/python3

Comment: @sahasrara62, thanks, but why are you talking about interpreter, whereas virtual envs are managed either by `venv` module or `virtualenv` and other packages, not the python interpreter?

Comment: venv and virtual env are not sperate tools or software, they are module/external of python interpreter which being used to create the virtualenvironments

Comment: @sahasrara62, okay, got that, thanks, but what is the algorithm to check for available module/package to create a virtual env as part of the defined interpreter? from the [docs page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html), it seems like it prefers `virtualenv` package for python > 3.3 and   `venv` for python interpreter > 3.3

Comment: dont know, need to go through the code